# Angularjs clear filter for ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have this ng-repeat condition:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(k, v) in loanapps | filter:{LoanStatus:SelectedStatus}:true track by $index">
    <td>
        {{v.Id}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{v.Name}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Filtering works fine when I have SelectedStatus value. Now I also want to reset the filter and display all the results.

I have this button click function:

```
$scope.ResetStatusFilter = function() {
    $scope.SelectedStatus = null;
}
```

I also tried:

```
$scope.ResetStatusFilter = function() {
    $scope.SelectedStatus = '';
}
```

But what this is doing is clearing out all the results.

Is there anyway how can I display all the results and exclude the filter once the button is clicked?

The select list is this one:

```
<select ng-model="SelectedStatus">
    <option value="Under Review">Under Review</option>
    <option value="Waiting for Meeting">Waiting for Meeting</option>
    <option value="Processing">Processing</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Use custom filter - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: thx @bhantol can you pls give me example how should I apply custom filter in my case, thanks

Comment: what is the default value of ```selectedstatus``` when the list first loads, and have you tried setting it back to that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing `filter:{LoanStatus:SelectedStatus}:true` to `filter:SelectedStatus`.

Comment: who will the table know for which field is that applied? Thx for help

Comment: Might want to refer to the documentation, but i believe the filter will search the whole object by default for your string value. Double check @ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 0):

Try this short circuiting technique.

```
<tr ng-repeat="(k, v) in loanapps | 
           filter: (LoanStatus.SelectedStatus &&
     {LoanStatus:SelectedStatus}:true) track by $index">
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using  `filter:{LoanStatus:SelectedStatus}:true` to  `filter:SelectedStatus`.

you can clear your filter by using

```
$scope.SelectedStatus ={}
```

it will clear the filter